# SwiftUI - NavigationBar not showing in Modal NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Trying to make a modal that's similar to the "Create Event" modal in Apple's Calendar app. I've got my modal successfully showing using the following code in a parent NavigationView:

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    Button(action: {
                        self.isModal = true
                        }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus").sheet(isPresented: $isModal, content: {
                            EventCreate(showModal: self.$isModal)
                        })
                    }
            )
```

The modal shows successfully, but I can't get a NavigationBar to show in the modal, which looks like this:

```
struct EventCreate: View {

    @Binding var showModal: Bool

    @State var event = Event(id: 0, title: "", description: "", location: "", start: Date(), end: Date(), cancelled: false, public_occurrence: false, created: "", last_updated: "", guests: -1)

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form{
                Section {
                    TextField("Title", text: $event.title)
                    TextField("Location", text: $event.location)
                }
                Section {
                    DatePicker(selection: $event.start, label: { Text("Start") })
                    DatePicker(selection: $event.end, label: { Text("End") })
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Create Event"), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(leading:
            Button("Close") {
                self.showModal = false
        })

    }
}
```

The app builds, and the Form is displayed, but the NavigationView doesn't:
[image: Screenshot of missing view]

How can I make this show? Or is there another view I should be using instead of NavigationView

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to put `navigationBarTitle` and `navigationBarItems` modifier inside the `NavigationView`, not outside it. These modifiers must be placed on the view that you are embedding, in your case the `Form`

```swift
struct EventCreate: View {

    @Binding var showModal: Bool

    @State var event = Event(id: 0, title: "", description: "", location: "", start: Date(), end: Date(), cancelled: false, public_occurrence: false, created: "", last_updated: "", guests: -1)

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form{
                Section {
                    TextField("Title", text: $event.title)
                    TextField("Location", text: $event.location)
                }
                Section {
                    DatePicker(selection: $event.start, label: { Text("Start") })
                    DatePicker(selection: $event.end, label: { Text("End") })
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Create Event"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
            Button("Close") {
                self.showModal = false
            })
       }
    }
}
```

This [article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-embed-a-view-in-a-navigation-view) by HackingWithSwift shows the correct placement.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it immediately!

Comment: @Andrew why modifier of `NavigationView` needs to be put inside NavigationView?
See for `Text` we are putting modifier on it, like `lineLimit` & `font`. Both the `NavigationView` & `Text` does inherits from base class i.e. `View` so why the difference? Any reason or article you can show me.

Comment: From Apples own [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation#set-up-navigation-between-list-and-detail) shows that it should be inside. This [medium article](https://medium.com/@michaellong/swiftui-deep-inside-navigationview-4d25d57a236c) gives a fairly detailed explanation as to why it is there.